# How to indicate an azureSubscriptionEndpoint in docker v2

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am updating an azure pipelines push.yml file. It contains code written in Docker v1 which I need to upgrade to Docker v2.
In Docker v1, one of the inputs parameters is "azureSubscriptionEndpoint". However, in the documentation of azure pipelines, which shows Docker v2 documentation only, I see no mention of this parameter. However, this parameter contains the name of the azure subscription, which I presume is essential information for azure. Is there some other way this needs to be specified in Docker v2.
By the way, I am an absolute beginner in this, so excuse me if any of my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: Hi didjek, Does my answer work by creating a new Docker registry service connection? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Edward, unfortunately there is something else blocking me from testing this at the moment, so I cannot check, however, I will validate your answer as soon as I can test it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If there is any update, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this [Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops), now its latest version is 2. Its `Docker Registry` paramater requires that you create a new [Docker Registry service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg).
[image]

If you choose `Azure Container Registry` as the `Registry type`, so you need to have an available Azure subscription, which is the value of the `azureSubscriptionEndpoint` parameter in previous Docker v1 and it also is the name of [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager).

```
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: buildAndPush
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'xxx'
    azureContainerRegistry: edwardregistery.azurecr.io
    command: buildAndPush
```

Therefore, if you use Docker v2 in push.yml file, the corresponding syntax should be

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'the name of Docker Registry service connection'
    repository: 'the name of the container repository.'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
```

You could use classic editor to view the details. And [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) lists the source code.